# pandas dataframe compare column to a constant

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a code like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a': 1, 'b': 2}])
df['c'] = min(5, df['a'] + df['b'])
```

my goal was to add a column 'c' to be the minimum of a constant number and the sum of column 'a' and 'b'. But Python gives error message on the second line like:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

What does this message mean? And how can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Note that [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) can't be used this way even without pandas, e.g. `min(5, [3])` is not valid. [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) accepts either an iterable _or_ individual values, not mixed. Specifically regarding pandas, see the extensive answers in [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36921951/13138364).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html) to set all values below 5 to 5:

```
df["c"] = df[["a","b"]].sum(axis=1).clip(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: min(5, sum(x.values)), axis=1)
```

Comment: note that `apply(axis=1)` technically works but is very slow (e.g. with a 10K rows, this is ~70x slower than the vectorized `sum`+`clip`)